# Как с помощью python requests повторить отловленный Fiddler-запрос?

Tags: python, requests, fiddler

Всем привет!
С помощью Fiddler отловил такой исходящий запрос (RAW):

```
POST https://account.rejoner.com/api/v1/user/signup HTTP/1.1
Host: account.rejoner.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 2663
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="96", "Google Chrome";v="96"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.1.2; SM-N975F) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.104 Mobile Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryKXAn4Aur4wlfjACa
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
X-Request-Id: 86c3d6b-d649-f6e2-a9f4-968c35b483d5
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Android"
Origin: https://account.rejoner.com
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: https://account.rejoner.com/signup?from=main_m_touch
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9
Cookie: 

------WebKitFormBoundaryKXAn4Aur4wlfjACa
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="extended"

true
------WebKitFormBoundaryKXAn4Aur4wlfjACa
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="more_password_strength"

1
------WebKitFormBoundaryKXAn4Aur4wlfjACa
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="context"

signup
------WebKitFormBoundaryKXAn4Aur4wlfjACa
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="browser"

{"screen":{"availWidth":"854","availHeight":"480","width":"854","height":"480","colorDepth":"24","pixelDepth":"24","availLeft":"0","availTop":"0"},"navigator":{"vendorSub":"","productSub":"20030107","vendor":"Google Inc.","maxTouchPoints":"5","doNotTrack":"inaccessible","hardwareConcurrency":"4","cookieEnabled":"true","appCodeName":"Mozilla","appName":"Netscape","appVersion":"5.0 (Linux; Android 7.1.2; SM-N975F) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.104 Mobile Safari/537.36","platform":"Linux i686","product":"Gecko","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.1.2; SM-N975F) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.104 Mobile Safari/537.36","language":"ru-RU","onLine":"true","webdriver":"false","pdfViewerEnabled":"false","deviceMemory":"4"},"flash":{"version":"inaccessible"}}
------WebKitFormBoundaryKXAn4Aur4wlfjACa
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="from"

main_m_touch
------WebKitFormBoundaryKXAn4Aur4wlfjACa
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="sent_me_ads"

true
------WebKitFormBoundaryKXAn4Aur4wlfjACa
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="sent_me_ads_common"

true
------WebKitFormBoundaryKXAn4Aur4wlfjACa
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

{"first":"Olya","last":"Monolya"}
------WebKitFormBoundaryKXAn4Aur4wlfjACa
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="birthday"

{"day":2,"month":4,"year":1986}
------WebKitFormBoundaryKXAn4Aur4wlfjACa
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="sex"

female
------WebKitFormBoundaryKXAn4Aur4wlfjACa
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="login"

monovaolya12
------WebKitFormBoundaryKXAn4Aur4wlfjACa
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="domain"

rejoner.com
------WebKitFormBoundaryKXAn4Aur4wlfjACa
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"

a=a=a=b=b=b=
------WebKitFormBoundaryKXAn4Aur4wlfjACa
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="restore"

{"secret":"-","secret_answer":"-","additional_email":"plalamomola12@yandex.ru"}
------WebKitFormBoundaryKXAn4Aur4wlfjACa
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="htmlencoded"

false
------WebKitFormBoundaryKXAn4Aur4wlfjACa
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="utm"

{"source":"","medium":"","campaign":"","term":"","content":""}
------WebKitFormBoundaryKXAn4Aur4wlfjACa--
```

Первая часть RAW это заголовки, вторая - содержимое формы, ну это и так очевидно.
Если я повторяю отправку этого запроса через сам Fiddler, то сервер возвращает мне положительный ответ. Но если я пытаюсь отправить это через `requests`, то возвращает ошибку.
Если я преобразую первую и вторую часть в соответствующие словари и подставляю в `requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)`, то сервер выдает ошибку. Если же вторую часть я подставляю в форму, но уже в виде `files=data` (так как форма всё таки `multipart/form-data`), то уже сам интерпретатор ругается, что `files` должен быть `bytes`, а не `dict`.

В общем вопрос простой. Как представленный запрос в точности повторить с помощью `requests`?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Приведите все ошибки, которые вы упоминаете, в явном виде в своём вопросе, вы можете его редактировать.